# Cassandra connection trouble spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I try to make a project Spring MVC in STS with Cassandra Database. I am new in using Cassandra DB for Spring MVC. 
I got this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : data.cassandra.CassandraDriver
    org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:296)
```

I have added the dependency for Cassandra Driver at my POM

This is a part of my Pom
    
        
            org.hibernate.ogm
            hibernate-ogm-cassandra
            5.0.0.Final

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-cassandra -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.cassandra/cassandra-driver-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

This is my **`Hibernate.cfg.xml`**

```
<session-factory>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
     cdata.cassandra.CassandraDriver
  </property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
     jdbc:cassandra:Database=libran;Port=9042;Server=127.0.0.1
  </property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
     root
  </property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">
     org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
  </property>
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>


  <mapping class="com.personal.myTrialApp.model.Link"></mapping>
```

This is my hibernate util

```
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

static 
{
      try 
      {
         Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();

         serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder()
            .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
               .buildServiceRegistry();

         sessionFactory = configuration
            .buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
      } 
      catch (HibernateException he) 
      {
         System.err.println("Error creating Session: " + he);
         throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(he);
      }
   }

   public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() 
   {
      return sessionFactory;
   }
```

and this is my object for table **`link`**

```
@Table("link") 
public class Link 
{
   @PrimaryKey
   private Integer linkID;

   private String name;

   private String address;
 // getter and setter
}
```

and this is my **`LinkDao`**

```
public class LinkDao 
{
   public static List<Link> getLink() 
   {
      Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
      List<Link> links = session.createQuery("from Link").list();
      return links;
   }

}
```

I want to get data from DB about linkID, name and address but I got that error. I hope I do not re-post, can anyone help me?
 Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case I don't use maven but added jars that needed for connection and also for query. you can see the image for the jars.
you can added the jars externally by:

- Right click the project and click add external jars.
- Navigate to your jars and add them.

[image]

Comment: let me try first, mate

Comment: I found the problem, it caused by name of cassandra jdbc driver, mate

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not getting the particlar Jar at runtime so go to pom.xml,
you can add a scope tag which means you want your dependency at the time of run time by default it is compile time.

    
        org.springframework.data
        spring-data-cassandra
        1.4.2.RELEASE
        runtime

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.cassandra/cassandra-driver-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

clean it and  install maven  and if it  still  gives the same problem then:

- click on the project.
- Select Properties.
- choose Deployment Assembly.
- Click on Add.
- Select Java Build Path Entries.
- Click on Maven dependencies.
- finish.

Comment: let me try it first, mate

Comment: when I select Java Build Path Entries, there are no option for Maven dependencies, mate

Comment: I found the problem about my case, and it's about Cassandra Driver Class Name. It should be "java.lang.AbstractMethodError" But thank you very much to help me, mate